# slow query - Search for Media Gallery

Tags: wp-query

after installing wordpress 4.7 Search for Media Gallery became very slowly performed.
here is a log falls into the slow-queries.log:

```
# Time: 2016-12-30T16:28:07.386551Z
# User@Host: info_234[info_234] @ localhost []  Id: 6390731
# Query_time: 4.187182  Lock_time: 1.953823 Rows_sent: 40  Rows_examined: 644073
SET timestamp=1483115287;
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS sq1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = sq1.post_id AND sq1.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ) WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%электр%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%электр%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%электр%') OR ( sq1.meta_value LIKE '%электр%' )))  AND (wp_posts.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%')  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 40;
```

tell me how to fix it?

Comment: what exactly is "Search for Media Gallery"? Just checking if this is a plugin?

Comment: Provide details what plugins do you use?

Comment: here. it is not a plugin https://screenshot.net/rmdowhq

Comment: I see now this is Media Gallery in WordPress.  @MaratPetrov, so what is the ~ number of posts you may have?

Comment: Do you have the query for WordPress 4.6?

Comment: i have 4.7. problems started when I upgraded wordpress

Answer (score -1):

> Time: 2016-12-30T16:28:07.386551Z
>   User@Host: info_234[info_234] @ localhost []  Id: 6390731
>   Query_time: 4.187182  Lock_time: 1.953823 Rows_sent: 40  Rows_examined: 644073
>
> SET timestamp=1483115287;
>
> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS sq1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = sq1.post_id AND sq1.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' ) WHERE 1=1  AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%электр%') OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%электр%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%электр%') OR ( sq1.meta_value LIKE '%электр%' )))  AND (wp_posts.post_mime_type LIKE 'image/%')  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'attachment' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'inherit' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 40;

I can tell the SQL query executes for 644073 posts, and this is a biggie.
It explains half of your problem. Maybe in WordPress 4.7 added a search based on `meta_value`, and probably you have many meta values in your structure. It would be interesting to compare this vs. the query in WordPress 4.6.

---

What you may do is to modify the `ajax_query_attachments_args` hook to make your query run faster.

```
File: wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php
2409:   /**
2410:    * Filters the arguments passed to WP_Query during an Ajax
2411:    * call for querying attachments.
2412:    *
2413:    * @since 3.7.0
2414:    *
2415:    * @see WP_Query::parse_query()
2416:    *
2417:    * @param array $query An array of query variables.
2418:    */
2419:   $query = apply_filters( 'ajax_query_attachments_args', $query );
2420:   $query = new WP_Query( $query );
```

I feel this is a separate question, if you have any problems, just let me know.

Comment: and what I need to fix it? in my file of the same code, as you pointed out

Comment: You need to find the way to alter the query.

Comment: Dont modify core files, it will just overwrite when you update WP core. I am having the same issue, will post a fix once I find it.

Comment: @Johan Pretorius I have not modified the core file, I just pointed where the hook is.

Comment: So i have found my issue. The issue for me was using MySQL 8 db engine, for some reason it doesnt like WP, I am still investigating why its doing it. I switched to MySQL 5.7 and that resolved the issue, also tested MariaDB 8 and that worked fine as well as Aurora with MySQL 5.7 and that also worked fine.